A 90s old west-style movie with a little person
I watched this film in the 90's, approximately 94 or earlier, on TV. What I remember of the story is that it is set in an old western style city but in the 1920s. A dwarf arrives in the city and no one likes him, but a woman who owns the town bar decides to give him a chance, and let him live in the bar loft and have him help her to take care of the bar. The plot changes a little when she decides to show him a brewery in the woods (I think it was a beer factory, I was 8 years old). Soon after that a new guy comes to town with villainous face and destroys the whole bar and as I recall kill the woman but leaves the dwarf alive. The dwarf then shows the villain where the beer factory is, and from what I understand we learn that they were working together the whole time to find out this information from the woman.

I updated the wording to try and make some sense of it. Feel free to revert my edit or update it if I got anything wrong of the details.

It sounds like The Ballad of the Sad Cafe (Simon Callow, 1991)

A tangled triangle. In the rural South of the early 20th century, Miss
  Amelia is the town eccentric, selling corn liquor and dispensing
  medicine. She takes in her half-sister's son, a diminutive crook-back
  named Lymon. He suggests they open a café in the downstairs of her
  large house. Marvin Macy gets out of prison and returns to town; turns
  out he was married to Amelia but it wasn't consummated. He pleaded,
  then got angry. Is he back for revenge? Eventually, Amelia and Marvin
  stage a no-holds-barred fight in the café. Lymon's complicated
  response to Marvin and to Cousin Amelia figures in the resolution.IMDB





Clip Ballad of the Sad Cafe
Trailer
